# Parsing text from Multiple Paragraph tags in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, html-parsing

I have a multiple Paragraph tags like below with same class attribute name **js-tweet-text tweet-text** need to parse the text in Android

```
    Caged parrot sings for its master. Industrialists &amp; IAS officers named in the charge sheet.
Sometext................
```

Html Text:

```
<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">Caged parrot sings for its master. Industrialists &amp; IAS officers named in the charge sheet. <a href="/PMOIndia" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link" dir="ltr" ><s>@</s><b>PMOIndia</b></a> &amp; MOS Coal left scot free.</p>


<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">Sometext................ <a href="/PMOInd" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link" dir="ltr" ><s>@</s><b>PMOIndia</b></a> &amp; MOS Coal left sc free.</p>
```

etc...

Could any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Jsoup Parser for this requirement in Android

```
 Docuument doc = Jsoup.connect("https://twitter.com/someperson/")
                           .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
                           .get();

Elements elements = doc.select("p[class=js-tweet-text tweet-text]");  

for (int j=0;j<elements.size();j++) {

                Element tmp = elements.get(j);
                String value = tmp.text();
        }
```

The above code will return all the class attribute text(which matches "js-tweet-text tweet-text")  value in Paragraph tag

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be done by a regex, but since i dont know what all to expect inside the tag, this would do,

```
    String input = "<p class=\"js-tweet-text tweet-text\">Caged parrot sings for its master. Industrialists &amp; IAS officers named in the charge sheet. <a href=\"/PMOIndia\" class=\"twitter-atreply pretty-link\" dir=\"ltr\" ><s>@</s><b>PMOIndia</b></a> &amp; MOS Coal left scot free.</p>";
    int i=0;
    boolean flag=true;
    String result="";
    for(i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {
        char c = input.toCharArray()[i];
        if(c=='<') flag = false;
        else if(c=='>')
        {
            flag = true;
            continue;
        }
        if(flag) result += c;       
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
Caged parrot sings for its master. Industrialists &amp; IAS officers named in the charge sheet. @PMOIndia &amp; MOS Coal left scot free.
```